# Dynamic router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I developed some kind of blog with VueJS and VueRouter. So I have a markdown editor in the administration in order to add blog posts.

My problem is: How to make `router-link`s work with dynamic content?

For the time being, I can only add classic `<a href="...">foo</a>` with the editor. And when the content gets rendered, it's a classic link so when a visitor clicks on the link, the entire website gets reloaded to display the content of the targeted link.

I think that the behaviour I'm looking for is to transform the internal links into `router-link` and the external links into classic links.

What is your strategy to achieve that in your projects, did someone had ever been confronted to that problem?

Thank you for your advices or ideas.

I explained my problem in a small JSFiddle if you want to see what I talk about: http://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/museptre/1/

```
const Home = { 
  template: '<div>Home <div v-html="dynamicContent"></div></div>',
  data () {
    return {
        dynamicContent: '<router-link to="/foo">This is a dynamic link</router-link> and <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">and this is a classic link</a>'
    }
  }
}
```

will only render the classic link

Comment: Have you try using `v-for` in the `router-link` ?

Comment: Also read https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Comment: I don't get it. All `router-link` params and tag content can be dynamic. What's the user story you can't achieve with it?

Comment: I made a JSFiddle with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/museptre/

Comment: Still not enough. `the entire website gets reloaded to display the content of the targeted link` ... could you say what do you expect other than this?

Comment: Well, as you can see, I can only use classic links in dynamic html, (the `<a href=""></a>` part.). The advantage of a `<router-link>` is that the page does not need to rerender completely. I want to use `<router-link></router-link>` in dynamic html. As you can see in my example, the dynamic `<router-link></router-link>` does not transform in a link when using `v-html`.

Comment: your fiddle is a naked, default router setup. It does not contain any of the code you show in your post, so it doesn't demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Woops, I'm sorry I did not save it, here is the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/museptre/1/

Comment: `v-html` just outputs the raw html just like using `innerHTML` so it not complied by vue, so the router-link is just ignored , same is the case with any data bindings

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem and I'm looking for a solution to solve that

Comment: @El_Matella my answer didn't help?

Comment: @mklimek I eddited your response with the solution I think is the best thats uses the render function. Thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, now I can see what you want to achieve.

Obviously, rendering `<router-link></router-link>` to static HTML won't work.

You need to generate `<rotuer-link>` in the template directly. You may use [render method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#render) to get more flexibility/dynamism or as Vue docs says:

> leverage the full programmatic power of JavaScript.

Then you bound `to` param and content of the link to some dynamic var eg. from `data` prop.

Example 1. with "simple dynamism" string template:

```
const Home = { 
  template: '<div>Home <router-link :to="dynamicTo">{{dynamicContent}}</router-link></div>',
  data () {
    return {
        dynamicContent: 'This is a dynamic link',
        dynamicTo: '/foo'
    }
  }
}
```

Example 2. with "more complex dynamism" and render method:

```
 render: function(createElement) {
    createElement(
      'router-link', {
        props: {
          to: this.dynamicTo
        }
      }, this.dynamicContent)
}
```

I didn't check the second example has valid syntax, but you've got an idea how you can use JavaScript to generate a fully customizable template (you can use loops, variables, etc).

It is possible to create a custom component solving the problem and using the render function:

```
export default {
    props: {
    content: {
        type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  render (h) {
    return h(Vue.compile(this.content))
  }
}
```

and using it this way:

```
<dynamic-vue-component :content="dynamic"></dynamic-vue-component>
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem solved: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/u4nx5k42/)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe kind of a hack, but I managed to work around this by adding an onclick attribute forcing the router to pick the link and preventing the page from reloading :

```
 <a href="/the-link/" target="_self" onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
 app._router.push('/the-link/');">Some text.</a>
```

Comment: A little bit hack, but `router-link` doesn't work for `v-html`, and that's the only one solution. +1!

Comment: This is clever, but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: app._router is undefined`. Any ideas? I also tried `this.$router`.